# Eclipse extension locationURI

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to add a new entry in location shown below. What is the locationURI of the menu below? Or arny other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but it seems that [Paul Webster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713646/paul-webster) is [on it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=112293).